# How to change values for axis in array of arrays (of arrays of arrays) in NumPy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a <s>4-level</s> 4-dimensional array `contours` (result of `cv2.findContours`) at the end of which I have pairs of coordinates. It looks like this:

```
print(contours[0][0])
→ [[ 676 4145]]
print(contours[0][0][0])
→ [ 676 4145]
print(contours[0][0][0][1])
→ 4145
```

I want to edit the <s>axis</s> element 1 of each of the last-level arrays so that the value is bigger by 10. I am aware of the [documentation](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/intro/numpy/operations.html), but I don't know how to apply it so deep without flattening. How to do that?

Comment: I think you've got your terminology muddled. It's "4-dimensional" or "4-axis", and by "axis 1" I think you mean "element 1"

Comment: I am pretty sure you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any of these would work:

- `contours[:,:,:,1] += 10`
- `contours[...,1] += 10`
- `contours += [0, 10]`

Comment: For `contours[:,:,:,1] += 10` it says "Invalid syntax", as expected; for `contours = contours[:,:,:,1] + 10` it says "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple", as well as for `contours[...,1] + 10`, while for `contours = contours + [0, 10]` it says "OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (npoints >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S)) in cv::pointSetBoundingRect". I haven't know these tricks, so thanks, but they seem to concern Python lists, not NumPy arrays.

Comment: There's no way that first one gives a `SyntaxError`. You must have typed it wrong, or added to it in an invalid way. For the second one, you must have lied in your question - it sounds like `contours` is a `list`, not an `np.array` The third one doesn't sound like it is coming from this line of code...

Comment: My bad, `contours` is a list, but its members are numpy arrays (`contours[0]`, `contours[0][0]` and `contours[0][0][0]`) until `contours[0][0][0][0]`, which is numpy int 32. Is there a way to do that in a simple way within a list or arrays, without using `for`?

Comment: I tried `contours = [c[:,:,1] + 10 for c in contours]`, but I get errors; for instance, `print(type(contours[0][0][0][1]))` returns `IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.` Is that because of different type of int for NumPy and Python?

Comment: `contours = [c[:,:,1] + 10 for c in contours]` is wrong because you just threw away `c[:,:,0]`

Comment: I've been trying to figure out what you meant the whole time, but I failed. How did I throw it away?

Comment: Ignoring the `+10`, it's the difference between `[c[:,:,:] for c in contours]` and `[c[:,:,1] for c in contours]`. The latter is only taking element `1`, whereas the former takes both.

Comment: Pardon me if I am being annoying, but I am still a bit confused after trying various methods. `contours = [c[:,:,:] + 10 for c in contours]` offsets both values, and I want to offset only one of them. I tried `contours = [c[:,:,:] + (0, 10) for c in contours]` but it doesn't work. So how do I modify one value and keep the other one intact within list comprehension?

Comment: @MrVocabulary: I'd expect that last one to work. Either way, without actually seeing how you constructed `contours`, I can't help you.

Comment: Okay, I got to it work another way (just manually looped through that). Thanks a lot, anyway, I learned a lot!